# Play Store app page loaded listener

Tags: android, google-play, listener, google-apps-marketplace, loaded

Is there a way to know when the Play Store app finished loading an app page?

I want to implement an animation drawn upon the screen(over the Play Store app) when it opened the link to my app and finished loading the page.

I did the animation over the screen, but at the moment I made it to start in one second, but one second is not enough for some older phones that move slow, or is too long for some new phones that are very fast. I want it to start precisely when the page has opened and finished loading, if not both, at least when the page has opened.(I say again that it is not instantaneously on many devices, especially the older ones)

To make it clear: I don't want to use WebView with onPageLoaded listener, I want to use the actual PlayStore app for loading the url to my app.

Comment: That sounds like a great way to clickjack.

Comment: This is the first time I heard about clickjack. I found out its meaning and I have no intention to do anything malicious. The animation is a small bubble that goes from bottom to top, hinting you must scroll down for rating the app.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I didn't mean to imply that you were doing something malicious, simply that if it were possible it would be ripe for abuse (and thus that I find the ability to do it very doubtful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to know when the Play Store app finished loading an app page?

No.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That's what I thought and that's what research has proven. It would be kind of invasive to know what other apps are doing I assume.